# shell for compressing files in batch

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a server where there are more than 5.4 million files with random nomenclatures. Now I want to write a shell script to compress those files into 1000 gz files of 5400 files in each. I also want to keep the log of each file is compressed in which gz file for the future reference. Is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 2):

I will suppose you have no "\n" in filenames and your shell is bash :

```
find /path -type f -print | split -l 5400 - filenames.
for f in filenames.*
do tar cvzf tarfile-${f#filenames.}.tar.gz -T $f
done
gzip -9 filenames.*
```

Where is the file "zzz" ?

```
zgrep zzz filename.*
```

If the comand returns "filename.XX.gz", the file is in "tarfile-XX.tar.gz"